# Why does outputing numpy.dot to memmap does not work?

Tags: python, numpy

If I do:

```
a = np.ones((10,1))
b = np.ones((10,1))
c = np.memmap('zeros.mat', dtype=np.float64, mode='w+', shape=(10,10), order='C')

a.dot(b.T, out=c)
```

I am getting:

> ValueError: output array is not acceptable (must have the right type,
>   nr dimensions, and be a C-Array)

I check all conditions from the error message and they seem to fit:

```
>>> print(a.dtype == b.dtype == c.dtype)
>>> print(np.dot(a, b.T).shape == c.shape)
>>> print(c.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'])

True
True
True
```

When I replace c with:

```
c = np.zeros((10,10))
```

it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using c = np.asarray(c) helps to fix the problem. (github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7124)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't just have to match the dtype; it also has to have the right *type*, as in `type(c)`. `c` is a `numpy.memmap` instance, not a `numpy.ndarray`, so that check fails.

As recommended in the [`numpy.memmap` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), you could instead use `mmap.mmap` to map the file and create a `numpy.ndarray` backed by the mmap as its buffer. You can look at the [`numpy.memmap` implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/core/memmap.py#L202) to see what might be involved in doing that.

Comment: I was able to make it work with the hints form: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7124. I used c = np.asarray(c).

Answer (score 0):

From [RKI's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796468/rki) comment, use of `numpy.asarray` works directly, e.g.:

```
a = np.ones((10,1))
b = np.ones((10,1))

c_memmap = np.memmap('zeros.mat', dtype=np.float64, mode='w+', shape=(10,10), order='C')
c = numpy.asarray(c_memmap)

a.dot(b.T, out=c)

c_memmap.flush()
#etc.
```